# Rewrite htaccess, redirect if a "+" exisit in the url like goo.gl

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, bit.ly, goo.gl

my question is: how to redirect url when it contains a "+" like `goo.gl` and `bit.ly`
a simple example 
`http://goo.gl/gogl+` it will be redirect to `http://goo.gl/info/gogl`

thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^\+]+)\+$ info/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That's correct @Gerben and `[L,R=301]` if OP wants permanent redirect.

Comment: Thanks very much **anubhava** and **Gerben** ,is exactly what i need :)